# Get a list of python's essential functions

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting

For syntax highlighting of Python in Python, I'm using the "keywords" module to get a list of the keywords (for, in, raise etc.).

But how can I get a list of essential built-in functions? I.E. the ones listed here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

(I want to do it programmatically of course, in case the list ever changes)

Comment: `dir(__builtins__)` perhaps?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in an imported module, only in the main module.

Comment: If you're trying to implement your own syntax highlighting, you might be better off looking at the python grammar.

Comment: Well, then `from __main__ import __builtins__ as builtins; dir(builtins)`. Cyclic imports ftw. (Damn, does not work in python2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dir(builtins)` is not enough, simply because [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) module also exposes exceptions and warnings, as well as `False`, `True`, `None` and lots of other constants and "internal" functions.

You could test the type of the object

```
import builtins # __builtin__ in Python 2
from inspect import isbuiltin

for name, val in vars(builtins).items():
    if isbuiltin(val):
        print(name)
```

but even then, in Python 3 the output would include `__build_class__` which isn't in the list of [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Really, it's fine to hardcode names of built-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of the builtins functions in python typing the following:

```
print dir(__builtins__)
```

Comment: Works in the interpreter, but not inside an imported module!